# Error "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH" with ApiGateway Custom Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, tls1.2, aws-acm, ssl-handshake

I am configuring a Custom Domain for ApiGateway. I created two subdomains, one for the Application Load Balancer and one for the ApiGateway. I imported a wildcard certificate on ACM for the two subdomains.

When I create a Custom Domain on ApiGateway and call the associated DNS I get the error "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH".

[ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILgJU.png)

The Application Load Balancer using the same certificate and it works.

When I call the ApiGateway with its DNS and it works. During the TLS handshake I get:

[ApiGateway TLS Handshake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf9YB.png)

When I call the ApiGateway with ApiGateway Custom Domain during the TLS handshake I get:

[ApiGateway CustomDomain TLS Handshake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq1NV.png)

It would appear that I am using a different version of TLS however in the CustomDomain I have set version 1.2

[ApiGateway CustomDomain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAxGA.png)
(I censored the domain)

What could be the error?

I expect to call the CustomDomain of the ApiGateway and get the correct response as I get it by calling the Application LoadBalancer.